# Primefaces7: How to use formular inputs as function parameters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I want to implement a login-functionality using user-input directly (w/o variables in handling bean).

After migrating to Primefaces, the xhtml-code code does not work anymore.

```
<h:form>        
    ...
            <h:outputLabel for="mail" value="Email:" />
            <p:inputText id="mail" value="#{mail}" required="true"/>
            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Passwort:" />
            <p:password id="password" value="#{password}" required="true"/>

                <p:commandButton value="Anmelden" update="loginGrowl" action="#{user.login(mail.value,password.value)}"/>
           ...
    </h:form>
```

It gives the error:

```
WARNUNG: #{user.login(mail.value,password.value)}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @43,122 action="#{user.login(mail.value,password.value)}": Property [value] not found on type [java.lang.String]
```

Comment: After migration from WHAT to PrimeFaces?
Does it work with h:* only components?

Comment: Most probably the original code used `binding` instead of `value` and this wasn't understood during "migration".

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that 'mail' and 'password' actually ARE the input strings.. So the following will work (JSF 2.3; PrimeFaces 7.0):

```
<h:form>        

        <h:outputLabel for="mail" value="Email:" />
        <p:inputText id="mail" value="#{mail}" required="true"/>
        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Passwort:" />
        <p:password id="password" value="#{password}" required="true"/>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Anmelden" action="#{user.login(mail,password)}"/>
        </f:facet>


</h:form>
```

I don't know when they changed it and I can't find anything documented so I'll leave the question here answered by myself for anyone who might stumble around.